# how place buttons from a component in the parent component block?

Tags: css, vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btc5v.png)I have a parent component to which I pass the slider component, but I want to put the buttons in the parent component block  But the css property z-index doesn't help.I attach the link https://codesandbox.io/s/new-dust-4rs28z?file=/src/App.vue https://codesandbox.io/s/new-dust-4rs28z?file=/src/App.vue:0-3427

I will be glad of your answer. I've been racking my brain for a couple of hours now. Thank you all in advance